# Flutter: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly"

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to run my Flutter app which uses Firebase and get the following error.  My app was running fine until I needed to run 'flutter upgrade' to make my app compatible with a new package I'm using (fl_chart).  Note that I am using an M2 Macbook.

Running pod install...                                             485ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  - FlutterMacOS
  - firebase_auth
  - firebase_core
  - path_provider_foundation
  - window_size

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `FlutterMacOS` from `Flutter/ephemeral`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from
`Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/macos`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from
`Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/macos`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from
`Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/darwin`
-> Fetching podspec for `window_size` from
`Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/window_size/macos`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is
  only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because
  checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.20.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists!
  Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_0_4.txt exists! Returning local because
  checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/0/4/Flutter/3.13.0/Flutter.podspec.json exists! Returning
  local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.18.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists!
  Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.12.0, ~> 10.12.0)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/macos`) was
    resolved to 4.16.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 10.18.0)


You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install
 --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/CoreOnly` inside your development pod
 `firebase_auth`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` to apply changes you've made.

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.r
b:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.r
b:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.r
b:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.r
b:257:in `process_topmost_state'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.r
b:182:in `resolve'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:
43:in `resolve'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb
:94:in `resolve'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/a
nalyzer.rb:1082:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interf
ace.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/a
nalyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/a
nalyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.r
b:422:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.r
b:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interf
ace.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.r
b:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.r
b:162:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/command/ins
tall.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in
`run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:
52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top
(required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
pod repo update

Exception: Error running pod install

I have tried solutions proposed in many other threads, including deleting ios/Pods/.. and Podfile.lock before reinstalling pod, changing all pod configurations to "None" in Xcode, simply running "pod repo update", etc and nothing seems to work.  I always get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried ``pod update Firebase/CoreOnly`` ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the Podfile is requesting incompatible versions of Firebase/CoreOnly. The Firebase versions requested in the Podfile need to be updated.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.12.0, ~> 10.12.0)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/macos`) was
    resolved to 4.16.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 10.18.0)
```